# Reading a plist file using MonoTouch

Tags: plist, xamarin.ios

What's the best way to load and process a "two-level nested" plist file using MonoTouch? I have a plist file with data (structurally) similar to the following:

```
- USA
--- New York
--- Chicago
- UK
--- London
--- Edinburgh
- France
--- Paris
--- Lyon
```

I have Obj C samples that use NSDictionary and NSArray, but I'd like to get it into a standard C# data structure as quickly as possible. I haven't been able to locate any complete examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the .NET System.Xml libraries to read it, as [.plist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list#Mac_OS_X) is simply an XML file. You have the choice of using XPath, looping with `XmlDocument/XmlNode`, or maybe even LINQ-To-XML (I'm not sure if this is supported on Monotouch).

You can find a lot of XML reading examples out there - `XmlReader` would be the fastest as it's forward only.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and I tried a lot of different options (including LINQ to XML). I ended up doing the following:

1. **[Convert plist to cleaner XML using XSLT](http://www.theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.xslt.php)**
2. **[Use XmlSerializer to load into strongly-typed classes](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/10/monotouch-rogets-1911-thesaurus.html)**

That seemed to be the best solution. Good luck!